# Is it possible to back-up a PS3 on an Internal HardDrive?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I am wondering if it is possible to back up a PS3 HardDrive onto an Internal Drive instead of an External Drive?
I have a 500Gb Internal Harddrive which I took out from my old laptop and connected to my PS3 using a SATA cable, but the console won't recognize it.
I made a 32Gb partition on the drive and the console can only read that 32Gb partition not the remaining free space on the drive.

I don't have an External HardDrive, can I use my Internal to entirely back-up my PS3 data?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to put your old PC internal drive in a usb drive enclosure then possibly re-partition and format it as FAT32. You can then plug it into the PS3 and backup from the internal drive to your new external drive. Since the backup/restore function is part of the PS3 software you have to boot it from the internal drive first.

Assuming your old PC drive has enough space to backup the PS3 in the first place of course.

Comment: I tried formatting it many times but it doesn't work, it only reads it if its below 32gb. I searched this problem up and I heard its because of copyright protection so it only works on a EXTernal hard drive and not an INTernal hard drive.
What do you mean by booting from the Internal drive first, you have to plug that in to your ps3 before turning on the playstation?

Comment: The PS3 runs from its internal drive only. Backup/Restore only work to/from an external drive, so the answer to your original question is NO. The internal drive is the one inside the PS3.  Your PC internal drive will only be accessible to the PS3 as an external drive. There is a support page for the PS3 backup utility which may explain it better than I have. Google 'ps3 backup'.